# Why do File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc and FileInfo.LastWriteTime return different values for GMT?

Tags: c#, file, datetime, fileinfo

So I have a file..

```
var myFile = C:\docs\MyFile.pptx
```

and when I noticed that

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(myfile);
var lastModified = fi.LastWriteTime;
```

and

```
var lastModified = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(myFile);
```

are returning different values. Why is this? The `FileInfo` value corresponds to the one displayed in Windows Explorer Date Modified column. Why do they differ? I would have expected them to would return exactly the same value.

Comment: What is your local timezone? `FileInfo.LastWriteTime` is probably returning a localized value.

Comment: Your question title  says different but your code is different

Comment: @ehsansajjad sorry, so it did, my bad. Corrected now

Comment: What's the difference between them? This info might help others to provide a useful answer.

Comment: And where does GMT come in? What values are you seeing? Your question is very unclear at the moment (especially with the first line of code, which wouldn't compile...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually checked the code in Reflector and they both do the exact same thing, i.e:

```
return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc((long) data.ftLastWriteTimeHigh << 32 | (long) data.ftLastWriteTimeLow);
```

vs

```
return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc((long) this._data.ftLastWriteTimeHigh << 32 | (long) this._data.ftLastWriteTimeLow);
```

I've also tested it and dates are the same. You must have accidentally compared Utc with a non-Utc function.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.